# Method works in the Rails Console - in a view throws an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Any help would be most appreciated.

This works in the rails console

```
@user1 = User.first
@user2 = User.last
@user1.follow.@user2

Friendship Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "friendships" ("follower_id", "followed_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["follower_id", 1], ["followed_id", 2], ["created_at", "2020-04-29 17:07:59.048027"], ["updated_at", "2020-04-29 17:07:59.048027"]]
```

Putting it into the view throws:

> NoMethodError in FriendshipsController#create undefined method `follow' for 2:Integer

- I have tried copying the follow method into my friendships controller - which did not make a difference.

FriendshipsController

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @u = current_user.id
    @u.follow(find_user.to_i)
    redirect_to :back, notice: 'Followed User.'
  end

  private
    def find_user
      params.require(:uid)
    end
end
```

friendship.rb

```
class Friendship < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :follower, class_name: 'User'
    belongs_to :followed, class_name: 'User'

    validates :follower_id, presence: true
    validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :active_friendships, class_name: 'Friendship', foreign_key: 'follower_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :passive_friendships, class_name: 'Friendship', foreign_key: 'followed_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :active_friendships, source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_friendships, source: :follower

  def follow(user)
    active_friendships.create(followed_id: user.id)
  end

  def unfollow(user)
    active_friendships.find_by(followed_id: user.id).destroy
  end

  def following?(user)
    following.include?(user)
  end
end
```

mark-up to generate the friend req

```
<%= button_to 'Unfollow', friendships_path(uid: @user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }  %>
```

I have been following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DwSxhgArFI

Comment: The error returned is pretty clear: you call the `.follow` method on an integer i.e. the current_user's id. Just change `@u = current_user.id` to `@u = current_user`

Comment: @Sovalina I am very much appreciative of your response. I would love to tell you your suggestion was clear, regrettably 2 weeks into my journey. I am still learning. Nevertheless, I tried your suggestion. It throws a different error `undefined method `id' for 1:Integer Did you mean? i` Referencing _ active_friendships.create(followed_id: user.id)_

Comment: @Sovalina I cracked my subsequent error `private
    def find_user
      User.find(params.require(:uid))
    end` Thank you for your help